# Proof by contradiction or contrapositive sets help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

so I'm having difficulties proving the following Theorem, through either proof by contradiction or contrapositive. Can someone please help me? The problem is as follows:

Prove that for any two sets, $A$ and $B$, $A \cap B$ and $A - B$ are disjoint where $A \cap B = \{x \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\}$ and $A - B = \{x \mid x \in A \text{ and } x \notin B\}$.

Comment: There's a guide for writing mathematics on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: Take an element $x$ in $A \cap B$. What property does $x$ have so that it doesn't belong to $A-B$.

Comment: In addition, please explain what difficulties you are having. Have you tried to assume there's some $x \in A \cap B$ that's also in $A - B$, and see what happens? That would be a proof by contradiction. I don't think contrapositive really applies here.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, the definition of "disjoint" means that the intersection is empty.

So, let us try a proof by contradiction. Suppose $A \setminus B$ and $A \cap B$ are not disjoint.

Then there is some $x \in (A \setminus B) \cap (A \cap B)$. Then $x \in (A \setminus B)$ and $x \in (A \cap B)$.

Now, can you take it from here, and see the contradiction that will arise?

Comment: What does the backward slash symbolize?

Comment: @Sanjay Some people write $A\setminus B$, rather than $A-B$, since the operation doesn't work _exactly_ like subtraction.

Comment: I still don't quite understand where to go from here. I'm struggling a lot with proofs. Can you please write out the solution and explain what is going on at each step? That would really help me understand.

Comment: @Sanjay: If $x\in B\setminus A$, then $x\in B$ and $x\notin A$; in particular, $x\notin A$. Is that possible when we know that $x\in A\cap B$?